# Why is Identity generating insecure redirect URIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Using Asp.Net Core 2.1.4. The app is behind an Nginx reverse proxy being run from the https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy docker image, which includes the x-forwarded-* header configuration.

In my `Startup.Configure` method, the first thing I do is:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
});
```

Then to setup external auth in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["FacebookAppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["FacebookSecret"];
})
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["GoogleClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["GoogleClientSecret"];
});
```

And to configure Identity:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then I have a controller action that my sign in form posts to:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

HTTP works on the whole site. I can see in Chrome dev tools that the call to the route that leads to `ExternalLogin' is made over https, but then the app redirects me to either Facebook or Google with a redirect_uri that is http. After authenticating and redirecting back to the http url, my app automatically redirects to https.

How can I make Identity generate secure redirect uris?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation provided in the .net core site:

---

If the app is deployed behind a proxy server or load balancer, some of the original request information might be forwarded to the app in request headers. This information usually includes the secure request scheme (https), host, and client IP address. Apps don't automatically read these request headers to discover and use the original request information.

The scheme is used in link generation that affects the authentication flow with external providers. **Losing the secure scheme (https) results in the app generating incorrect insecure redirect URLs.**

---

To solve this you can try changing nginx configurations and get more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-nginx)

Comment: I should have mentioned nginx is being run from the https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy docker image, which includes the x-forwarded-* header configuration.